# Multiple activities shown on overview screen

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

When I start new activity in my application with startActivity(intent), if I don't finish the previous activity, all of the activities are shown in recent apps list with their label names. I don't use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and could not find the reason why this happens.

[image]

Comment: Are all these activities belong to the same app, or different app?

Comment: same app, this screenshot is not of my app but like that happens to me

Comment: @AnaKoridze Maybe you should add a note to clear it for other viewers, something like: *Simulation (using other apps) of how my activities are shown in recent apps*. Maybe not the best explanation xd

Comment: Also, show us how you launch new activities

Comment: it was because of activity launchmode singleinstance, MainActivity had this launchmode and it was shown in recent apps always, but not on every phone